# Creating a service for a DaemonSet

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to reach a DaemonSet listening on port 18081 via a service but unsucessfully so far.

The pod that was started by the DaemonSet works correctly. I can port-forward to the pod and port 18081 and talk to exposed API on the port.

The service for the DaemonSet is configured as follows:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: monerod-service
spec:
  selector:
    name: monerod
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 18081
```

In the Kubernetes UI (kubectl proxy) the correct Pod is selected in the service, so the pod selectors seems to be fine.

I can execute a ping on the pod that needs to connect to monerod-service and the correct IP is shown. But connection to the port via curl fails (same curl works in the port-forward test).

What am I missing in the configuration. Is there a difference between DaemonSet/Deployment service creation?

---

More playing around with Kubernetes

I played around with the service and DaemonSet. I converted the DaemonSet to a "normal"
Deployment, but the same behaviour is shown. So the behaviour has nothing to do with DaemonSets. It has to be something else with services/pods I do not understand.

I created the service now with:

```
kubectl expose deployment monerod-deployment --type=ClusterIP
```

and this results in the following service:

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "monerod-deployment",
    "namespace": "default",
    "labels": {
      "app": "monerod"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 18081,
        "targetPort": 18081
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "app": "monerod"
    },
    "clusterIP": "<some-ip>",
    "type": "ClusterIP",
    "sessionAffinity": "None"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {}
  }
}
```

That looks pretty good. That should expose port 18081 for other services only in the cluster.

If I execute now a

```
curl -X POST http://monerod-deployment:18081/json_rpc ...
```

in the pod that should talk to the monerod service this results in

```
port 18081: Connection refused
```

In the monerod-deployment docker container the container is exposed (with EXPOSE 18081)
and the the deployment has the following port definition:

```
"ports": [
  {
    "containerPort": 18081,
    "protocol": "TCP"
  }
],
```

Doing a port-forward to the deployment with kubectl and executing the curl locally works perfectly fine.
I do not understand, why the connection from the pod to the monerod-deployment cannot be established.

Answer (score 2):

Found out was wrong, it was nothing in Kubernetes.

The monerod daemon does only allow connections from localhost by default, for security reason. Enabling external connections '--confirm-external-bind' made it work.

The link to https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#running-commands-in-a-pod from Baltazar was very helpful finding out was is going on and elimanting all causes in Kubernetes one by one!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify in your service definition the targetPort.  The targetPort is the port your pod exposes.  You can have a different port defined in your service.

Like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: monerod-service
spec:
  selector:
    name: monerod
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9091
    targetPort: 18081
```

The port is not readily visible from outside the cluster, you can either use the nodePort type or ingress.

Comment: The service definition now looks like your suggestion (I created the service again with kubeclt expose this time, see edit in original question). And this should expose the service. Having the service only available in the cluster is desired. The main problem that remains: Why can I not make a curl requested to the exposed service?

Comment: I am going to take a wild guess, im also learning kubernetes.  Could it be that the pod doing the curl is in a different namespace?

Comment: Btw, you may want to check kubernetes docs on debugging services.  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#running-commands-in-a-pod

Answer (score 0):

Probably releated to this error in kube-proxy on Kubernetes 1.8 on Azure:
[kube-proxy fails - native loadbalancing fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162005/kube-proxy-fails-native-loadbalancing-fails)